# TrueLicense java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, licensing, keystore, truelicense

I'm following this tutorial http://alvinalexander.com/java/true-license-java-software-license-server to attempt to set up a license server on my VPS. However for the last while, I've been getting this error `java.IO.Exception: Invalid keystore format` as displayed below and can't figure out how to fix it.

[image]

Now to be perfectly honest, i don't know much about keystore formats apart from what I've learned in the past few days. The keystore file is name `dcPrivateKey.keystore` as the examples in the link suggests which contains a password. Does anyone harbour an idea of how to resolve this issue?

**Edit**

After a suggestion from @parsa porahmad i managed to generate an appropriate `.keystore` file. However after trying afew different methods such as removing and recreating the `.keystore` file i am stumped by this error.

[image]

Comment: get a help of `%JDK_HOME%/keytool`

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: use the `keytool.exe` application which is located under java bin folder, it will help you for managing your keys and related stuffs

Comment: "for the last while" <-- what do you mean? The same code worked before?

Comment: @fge No, since i started the project.

Comment: @parsaporahmad Thanks for the suggestion, that seems to have solved that problem however, I've updated the OP with the issue I've run into now.

Comment: Does your KeyStore have a private key in it?

Comment: @EJP Yes, turns out i just had to change it to match my keystore password. Everything seems to work now, my license files are being generated.